# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'end'. error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select *
from DBNAME.dbo.Shell_V36 V
inner join 
DBNAME.DBO.Promo P 
on 
Case  
when 
(V.Product = P.From_Product_Code) 
And  (V.cur_date >= P.Promo_end_date)
or (V.cur_date <= P.Promo_start_date)
then (P.To_Product_Code)
else(P.From_Product_Code)
end
```

i am getting "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'end'." can any one help me out please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'END'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018549/an-expression-of-non-boolean-type-specified-in-a-context-where-a-condition-is-ex)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate--it has the same question title, but the question specifics and the answer are different

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the field from `Shell_V36` table used in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` operation:

```sql
select *
from DBNAME.dbo.Shell_V36 V
inner join DBNAME.DBO.Promo P 
on Case when 
           (V.Product = P.From_Product_Code) And  
           (V.cur_date >= P.Promo_end_date)
           or 
           (V.cur_date <= P.Promo_start_date)
         then (P.To_Product_Code)
         else (P.From_Product_Code)
   End = V.code -- presumably code field should be used
```